# Radius of convergence for the power series

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I have a feeling I am making a very silly mistake here but is the limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac {zn^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}| =|z|$ ?

just need a confirmation.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work like this:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{zn^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\bigg|=\lvert z\rvert\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\bigg|=\lvert z\rvert\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{1}{n}\bigg|=0.$$
The third equality follows from expanding the denominator. We can see that the dominating term is the term with power $(n+1)$: that is $n^{n+1}$. If we divide the numerator and denominator by $n^n$ and take the limit, we get the result.

Comment: Or observe that $n^n/(n+1)^{n+1}=[(n/(n+1))^n]/[n+1]<1/[n+1].$.........+1

Comment: That works too!

Answer (score 0):

You should know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left( \dfrac n {n+1}\right)^n = \dfrac 1 e,$ and what you've got is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left( \dfrac n {n+1} \right)^n \cdot \dfrac 1 {n+1}. $